# Вывод числа в консоль

Tags: ассемблер

Не могу понять как мне вывести число не входящее в *ASCII*. Например, если у меня число 5 то я просто его перевожу в *ASCII* и вывожу, а как быть если число 99992 (на чистом, без всяких макросов и плюшек)?

```
section .data                            
value db 5

section .text          
global _start

_start: 

mov ecx, [value]
add ecx,0x30 
mov [value],ecx




mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, value
mov edx, 5
int 80h


mov eax, 1
mov ebx, 0
int 80h
```

Использую NASM, запускаю на linux

Comment: Разбей посимвольно и переведи в ASCII . 

Так не подойдет ?

Comment: Какой ассемблер-то? На каком процессоре? Надо писать конвертор из hex в ascii, некий аналог `itoa()`. Или где-то найти готовый и не мучаться.

Comment: да и можно было бы эту супер программку тиснуть в вопрос.

Comment: @A.Toumantsev готово )

Comment: Что за ось? Если венда - можно itoa юзать.

Comment: "Надо писать конвертор из hex в ascii" - разве данные в регистрах храняться не в двоичной форме? Почему из hex?

Comment: Однофигственно, 1 хексовая цифра однозначно соответствует 4 последовательным двоичным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот, как вариант:

```
sub esp, 12      ; создаём буфер под строку на 10 цифр
mov edi, esp       ; (по числу 10-ичных разрядов в 32-битном числе) 
add edi, 11          ; + знак (для чисел со знаком)
mov byte ptr[edi], 0  ; + /0 на конце, чтобы обозначить конец строки 

mov eax, value  ; value - исходное число

; для беззнаковых чисел вся эта часть (до метки convert) не нужна
mov esi, eax    ; в esi будет храниться знак
shr esi, 31
test esi, esi      ; проверяем является ли число отрицательным
jz convert      ; если нет - переходим сразу к конвертации
mov ecx, 0      ; если да - делаем его положительным
sub ecx, eax
mov eax, ecx

convert:
  mov ecx, 10
loop_begin:
  sub edi, 1   ; запись идёт с конца, поэтому указатель сдвигается к началу
  xor edx, edx
  div ecx         ; делим value на 10, в остатке получаем младший разряд
  add edx, '0'    ; конвертируем его в цифру
  mov byte ptr[edi], dl  ; записываем цифру в буфер
  cmp eax, 0      ; проверяем все ли разряды вычислены
jg loop_begin     ; для беззнаковых - ja

; добавляем знак "-", если нужно (только для чисел со знаком)
test esi, esi
jz done
sub edi, 1
mov byte ptr[edi], '-'

done:
; строка готова , указатель на неё в edi
; в этом месте должен быть вывод на экран

; потом удаляем буфер, когда он уже не нужен
add esp, 12
```